# How can I turn off "convert and copy" dialog for Windows Portable Devices?

Tags: windows-7, mp3, windows-media-player

Under Windows 7, when I copy an mp3 file to my iRiver H10 I always get a dialog box offering to "convert and copy" the file, or "No, just copy".  The mp3 files are not copy protected.  The H10 is an mp3 & wma player connected via USB, but does not show up as a drive letter.  It shows up in the Windows Explorer as an attached device.  This is a PlaysForSure device that Microsoft wants you to access through their Multimedia player, which I don't use.

How can I disable this dialog box and always just copy the file?

I'm hoping there's a registry entry, or possibly a group policy setting, but I'm not above patching a dll.  My google search turned up the fact that the dialog box strings appear in wpdshell.dll.  WPD apparently stands for Windows Portable Devices.

Comment: This was answered [here (SuperUser.com)](http://superuser.com/questions/402225/disable-prompt-to-convert-videos-copied-to-media-device)